# select the first row of a joined database

Tags: mysql, database, join, row

I need to select the first row of a database joined with another main database.
The main database collects informations about dogs, their race, size, name eccc…
The joined database is linked to the frist and provide dog’s images.
Each dog has different images, more than one.
In the list page of the dogs, I need to show, for each dog, all dog’s details and only the frist image of the joined database, as it was the profile image.

So here u are the structure of the two databases:

```
//dog_pages database:

id
--
slug
--
name
--
race
--
size
--
description
--
created
--
updated
```

and:

```
//dog_images database:

id
--
dog_page_id  //this is for the join
--
content
--
img_title
--
img_url
--
img_ftp_path
--
thumb_ftp_path
--
thumb_delete_path
```

I use this code to generate the query:

```
SELECT dog_pages.id, dog_pages.slug, dog_pages.name, dog_pages.race, dog_pages.size, dog_pages.description, dog_pages.created, dog_pages.updated, dog_images.id, dog_images.dog_page_id, dog_images.img_url, dog_images.thumb_ftp_path, dog_images.content AS image_content

FROM dog_pages

LEFT JOIN dog_images

ON dog_pages.id = (
    SELECT dog_images.dog_page_id
    FROM dog_images
    WHERE dog_pages.id = dog_images.dog_page_id
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Unfortunately this doesn’t work, the results is to have more than one image for each dog. I needjust one, that in the frist row of the dog_images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple methods (including variables).  But, taking your method, you can use an aggregation function instead of `limit`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.slug, p.name, p.race, p.size, p.description, dog_pages.created, p.updated,
       i.id, i.dog_page_id, i.img_url, i.thumb_ftp_path, dog_images.content AS image_content
FROM dog_pages p LEFT JOIN
     dog_images i
     ON p.id = i.dog_page_id AND
        i.id = (SELECT MIN(i2.id)
                FROM dog_images i2
                WHERE p.id = i2.dog_page_id
               );
```

Comment: Man it works! I need to study this code, it is really new to me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In the second select you are choosing only Id for joining and you can replace it just with

..=dog_images.dog_page_id
It's exactly what you get from the select

To solve the problem try to use group by dog_pages_I'd

And you should get information only about one image

Comment: The solution of Gordon seems to work pretty well for me, but thanks for teh answer!